# Generic way to smoothly change the position of an HTML element as other elements appear and disappear

Tags: javascript, css

I don't have a good enough understanding of web development to be able to tell if my question is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12910213/animate-ease-an-element-to-position-when-other-elements-disappear), so apologies if this is a duplicate.

I'm planning to have a lot of different pages in my website, all structured differently, all of which need to look reasonable on a variety of different screen sizes. These pages will include and/or link-to code that makes various bits of content appear and disappear. On some of these pages however I'm finding there's too much appearing and disappearing all at once and the reader gets confused about exactly what has changed. To solve this, I'd love to write either some CSS or some JS for ensuring that when the position of an element changes, it smoothly moves into the new position instead of just jumping there. Hopefully, this will help the end-user better understand how the content has changed.

I'm currently trying to do this with CSS using a "transition" applied to the "position" attribute, but to no avail. Here's the code:

```js
function toggleVisibility(elementId) {
  var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
  if (element.style.display === "none") {
    element.style.display = null;
  } else {
    element.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
#lol {
  position: relative;
  transition: position 2s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Title</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body>
  <div id="foo"> foo </div>
  <div id="bar"> bar </div>
  <div id="lol"> lol </div>
  <button onmouseup="toggleVisibility('bar')"> Click me</button>
</body>
```

This doesn't do anything helpful, unfortunately. There's no smooth transition; the text that says "lol" jumps around instantaneously.

Ideas, anyone? A javascript solution is fine, but I'm looking for something that's generic enough that it can be applied anywhere on the page without precomputing any values, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the height of your elements, `auto` won't animate. Also you shouldn't use ids to style objects, is better to use a class so that you don't have specificity problems.

Here's a working example, I added also `opacity` and `overflow: hidden` to make the item disappear:

```js
function toggleVisibility(elementId) {
  var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
  element.classList.toggle("hidden");
}
```

```css
.item {
  position: relative;
  height: 20px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: height 0.5s, opacity 0.3s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;
}
.hidden {
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Title</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body>
  <div id="foo" class="item"> foo </div>
  <div id="bar" class="item"> bar </div>
  <div id="lol" class="item"> lol </div>
  <button onmouseup="toggleVisibility('bar')"> Click me</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Looks great, and I love the fade-in/fade-out effect :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all according to W3C [(read for  more)](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transitions-1/#animatable-properties)`display` is  not a animateable property. So when you change the `display` from `block` to `none` or vice versa you can not animate this change.
But in order to achieve what you want is you can use the `height` property. When hiding the element you need to do is set the height to 0. And add transitions to that and that will do the trick.

Also  in order for you to use this throughout your application use a class say `hidden` and whenever you want any element to hide with animation add this class to that. Below is a working snippet of the same.
Also for the above to work you need to give your element some initial height as transitions wont work with `height: auto`

```js
function toggleVisibility(elementId) {
  var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
  if (element.style.height === "0") {
    element.classList.remove('hidden');
  } else {
    element.classList.add('hidden');
  }
}
```

```css
div.hidden {
  -moz-transition: height .8s;
  -ms-transition: height .8s;
  -o-transition: height .8s;
  -webkit-transition: height .8s;
  transition: height .8s;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

div {
  height: 20px;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Title</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body>
  <div id="foo"> foo </div>
  <div id="bar"> bar </div>
  <div id="lol"> lol </div>
  <button onmouseup="toggleVisibility('bar')"> Click me</button>
</body>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Looks great! <obligatory filler to get over character limit here>